How to stop a thread in Delphi?
I have a button1 and a label1. When the button1 is clicked, the label1 starts counting up on its own thread.
The issue is that I have NOT been able to stop the thread when button2 is clicked.
Here's the code I'm working with:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.SyncObjs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private

  public

  end;

{ TMyThread is the class that will handle background work for Label1 }
  MyThread1 = class(TThread)
  private
    count: Integer;
    msg: string;
    stopThread:boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdateUI;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ MyThread Constructor }
constructor MyThread1.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False); // False means it will start right away
  FreeOnTerminate := True; // Free memory when finished
end;

{ Worker Thread for Label1 }
procedure MyThread1.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    //Check to see if the was terminated. If so, then exit the for loop.
    if Terminated then
      Exit;

    Sleep(10); // Simulate work (1 second per iteration)
    msg := '# ' + IntToStr(i);
    Synchronize(UpdateUI); // Update UI safely from the main thread
  end;

  Synchronize(UpdateUI);
end;

{ Update the UI for Label1 }
procedure MyThread1.UpdateUI;
begin
  Inc(count);
  Form1.Label1.Text := msg;

  //WHen finished:
  if (count = 1000) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Thread 1 Finished!');
  end;
end;

{Start the thread when button1 is clicked}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyThread1.Create; // Create and start the first thread for Label1
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Procedure to stop the MyThread1 thread goes here.
end;

end.

I tried to stop the thread and it did not stop.
What exactly could the issue be with why I cannot terminate this thread?

You are not using the stopThread member, so get rid of it. Your thread's Execute() code is looking at the thread's Terminated property, so call the thread's Terminate() method.
However, your button1 is not saving the thread object it creates, so button2 is not able to access it.
Try something more like this:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.SyncObjs;

type
  MyThread1 = class;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FMyThread: MyThread1:
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
  public
  end;

{ TMyThread is the class that will handle background work for Label1 }
  MyThread1 = class(TThread)
  private
    count: Integer;
    msg: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure UpdateUI;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

{ MyThread Constructor }
constructor MyThread1.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True); // True means it will not start right away
  FreeOnTerminate := True; // Free memory when finished
end;

{ Worker Thread for Label1 }
procedure MyThread1.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 1000 do
  begin
    //Check to see if the thread was terminated. If so, then exit the for loop.
    if Terminated then
      Break;

    Sleep(10); // Simulate work (1 second per iteration)
    msg := '# ' + IntToStr(i);
    Synchronize(UpdateUI); // Update UI safely from the main thread
  end;

  Synchronize(UpdateUI);
end;

{ Update the UI for Label1 }
procedure MyThread1.UpdateUI;
begin
  Inc(count);
  Form1.Label1.Text := msg;
end;

{Start the thread when button1 is clicked}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FMyThread <> nil then Exit;
  FMyThread := MyThread1.Create; // Create and start the first thread for Label1
  FMyThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  FMyThread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Procedure to stop the MyThread1 thread goes here.
  if FMyThread <> nil then
    FMyThread.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //WHen finished:
  FMyThread := nil; 
  ShowMessage('Thread 1 Finished!');
end;

end.


Isn't there a race condition between 1) the test for FMyThread<>nil, 2) FMyThread:=nil, and 3) FMyThread.Terminate ?

@AndersMelander No, because all three are being done in the main thread. The TThread.OnTerminate event is synchronized by default (you can override TThread.DoTerminate() to change that)

Yes, you are right.

As a tiny additional point: shouldn't FreeOnTerminate := True ideally be done before inherited Create(True) in constructor MyThread1.Create? Without that, they thread may theoretically run and terminate before the FreeOnTerminate := True statement is executed?

@MatthiasB No, because Create(True) is constructing the thread with CreateSuspended=True, so the thread will not begin running until you call Start() or Resume() explicitly. But, even when constructing with CreateSuspended=False. the thread will not begin running until after the most derived constructor has exited (since Delphi 6). So, you can safely set FreeOnTerminate at any time in any constructor, or also inside of Execute()/DoTerminate() before the thread has finished running.
